# How to use a case clause in the query below without having errors?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was trying to write a Postgresql query that allows me to run a subquery within my query only if a certain condition is met:

```
select sum("TotalBookings") as Availability
from ( 
  select -count(*) as "TotalBookings" 
  from bookings 
  where hotel_id=4 
    and ('2023-02-24') between symmetric check_in_date and check_out_date
  union 
  select count (*) as "TotalRooms" 
  from rooms 
  where rooms.hotel_id=4
) Availability
```

The query above returns the information needed (Availability) and I would like to show n amount of rooms (select * from rooms) if availability >=1 .

How can I go around this? Should I use a CASE expression? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Yes, use a case expression!

Comment: No need for `between symmetric` here, check_in_date should never be after check_out_date. (Have a constraint!)

Comment: I would change check_in_date and check_out_date to a single column of range type tsrange. This gives you the option to use a constraint, but also to play with the check in time and check out time. Also for a late check out, if that's possible or not. Check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Comment: The problem here is that if I use a case statement like this one it throws an error:   select sum("TotalBookings") as Availability
   from(select -count(*) as "TotalBookings" from bookings where hotel_id=4 and ('2023-02-24') between symmetric check_in_date and check_out_date
          union 
         select count (*) as "TotalRooms" from rooms where rooms.hotel_id=4) Availability
         case
          when Availability >=1 then (select * from bookings where hotel_id=4)
         end